# How can I restrict GitLab CI jobs to certain refs but only merge requests and manual starts?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab CI job that I'd like to run only for merge requests (and manual pipeline starts) to specific branches.

I can restrict it to merge requests and manual starts if I say

```
 only:
    - merge_requests
    - web
```

And I can restrict it to only certain branches by saying

```
  only:
    - /^issue-.*$/
  except:
    - branches
```

but I cannot seem to find a way to run the job only if both of those conditions are true. I tried adding all the conditions to the only section, and tried using except to filter out all branch names that didn't match "issue-" but neither of those seemed to work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you can do this by using variables and CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME. (which is the branch associated with the pipeline trigger)

```
only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
      - web
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^issue-.*$/
```

only will logical-AND across refs and variables, and logical-OR within those categories, so this translates to "match when (refs is merge_requests OR refs is web) AND (variable CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME starts with issue-)